# show list of items from a table that is referenced by foreign key to a userprofile table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-5

I am very new to MVC5 and trying to put together a small to do list application. I have created a UserLogin table with username and password, and a UserProfile table with all other information about the user. These tables and the correlating functionality I have working fine. Users can register, log in, log out and the applicable tables will be updated.

I also have a do do list table with the items users want to add. This is where I am having trouble. I cannot figure out how to reference the specific users and display the todolist table info that is specific to that user.

Account Controller:

```
using MyToDoListApplication.Models.EntityManager;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using ToDoListApplicationNew.Models.DB;
using ToDoListApplicationNew.Models.ViewModel;

namespace ToDoListApplicationNew.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Account
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        #region signup methods
        // Get method for signup page
        public ActionResult SignUpPage()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // Post method for signup page - post to db
        [HttpPost]
        // Pass in the UserSign up model object to be built
        public ActionResult SignUpPage(UserSignUp USUV)
        {
            // Form is filled out and then method is entered
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Form is filled out and database connection is established if form is valid
                UserProfileManager UPM = new UserProfileManager();

                if (!UPM.isLoginReal(USUV.Username))
                {
                    // data access . adduseraccount from entity manager (where model objects are built)
                    UPM.AddUserAccount(USUV);
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(USUV.FirstName, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home");
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            return View();
        }
        #endregion

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(UserLoginView ULV, string returnURL)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UserProfileManager UPM = new UserProfileManager();
                //retrive the password using the GetUserPassword() from UserProfileManager
                // This will pass the user name to the gup method and if the username and password exist
                // it will redirect the user to the welcome page.
                string password = UPM.GetUserPassword(ULV.Username);

                // If password is wrong or blank, catch with error message to user
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user login or password provided is incorrect");
                }
                else
                {
                    if(ULV.Password.Equals(password))
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(ULV.Username, false);
                        return RedirectToAction("_UserHome", "Account");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The password provided is incorrect");
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult SignOut()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        #region UserHome 
        // After Login User is redirected to the _UserHome.cshtml view
        // This is where listItems should be showing up
        // MyList viewModel
        public ActionResult UserHome()
        {
            if (Session["UserLoginID"] != null)
            {
                using (ToDoDBEntities db = new ToDoDBEntities())
                {
                    return View(db.MyListItems.ToList());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("LogIn");
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is my class for managing my entity connections:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ToDoListApplicationNew.Models.DB;
using ToDoListApplicationNew.Models.ViewModel;

namespace MyToDoListApplication.Models.EntityManager
{
    public class UserProfileManager
    {
        public void AddUserAccount(UserSignUp newUser)
        {
            // create database connection
            using (ToDoDBEntities db = new ToDoDBEntities())
            {
                // Collect viewmodel data
                // Here building goes by object type and not foregin key relationship
                UserLogin UL = new UserLogin();
                UL.Username = newUser.Username;
                UL.Password = newUser.Password;

                // Add the UserLogin object I just built to the database
                db.UserLogins.Add(UL);
                db.SaveChanges();

                UserProfile UP = new UserProfile();
                // establish connection to UL by establishing foreign key relationship
                UP.UserLoginID = UL.UserLoginID;
                // Now add the new table properties to the new object
                UP.FirstName = newUser.FirstName;
                UP.LastName = newUser.LastName;
                UP.CreationDate = newUser.CreationDate;
                UP.Email = newUser.Email;

                // Add UserProfile object to databse and save changes
                db.UserProfiles.Add(UP);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        //Check if user is real before login is allowed
        public bool isLoginReal(string LoginName)
        {
            using (ToDoDBEntities DB = new ToDoDBEntities())
            {
                // Return the user from the DB whose login name matches the LoginName string passed in as perameter
                return DB.UserLogins.Where(o => o.Username.Equals(LoginName)).Any();
            }
        }

        // Check if password exists
        public string GetUserPassword(string loginName)
        {
            using (ToDoDBEntities db = new ToDoDBEntities())
            {
                // retrieves user by comparing the username to the loginname passed in as a perameter
                var user = db.UserLogins.Where(o => o.Username.ToLower().Equals(loginName));
                if (user.Any())
                    return user.FirstOrDefault().Password;
                else
                    return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my UserHome view. What I am trying to do is have the user redirected here once he or she logs in and have their to do list display on this page

```
@model IEnumerable<ToDoListApplicationNew.Models.DB.MyListItem>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserHome";
}

<h2>UserHome</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemImportance)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserProfile.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemImportance)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserProfile.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.MyToDoListID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.MyToDoListID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.MyToDoListID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I have also attached an image of the database design.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9tLh.jpg)

So, My login and sign up functionality works great. I originally just had them redirected to a "Welcome" page that said essentially hi user, welcome. But this was just while I was testing the login. Now, I have added this 3rd table for to do list items. I have the edmx updated. I also have this viewmodel that I am not currently using (I built it when I though I had an idea on how to do this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ToDoListApplicationNew.Models.ViewModel
{
    public class userListViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int MyToDoListID { get; set; }

        public int UserProfileID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name =" Date of input")]
        public DateTime ItemDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [Display(Name ="New Item")]
        public string Item { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [Display(Name ="Importance level (1 - 10")]
        public int ItemImportance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help. If something doesnt make sense please let me know and I will try to explain it the best I can.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You should add this navigation property to your userListViewModel class:

```
public UserProfile UserProfile{ get; set;}
```

After this the View should work (cshtml file).

But assuming you use EntityFramework, another problem could be that your navigation property is empty.
Try changing the UserHome action like this:

```
public ActionResult UserHome()
{
    if (Session["UserLoginID"] != null)
    {
        using (ToDoDBEntities db = new ToDoDBEntities())
        {
            // Include fetches the data behind navigation properties
            return View(db.MyListItems.Include(x => x.UserProfiles).ToList());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("LogIn");
    }
}
```